# How to change the background Color of Fullcalendar day field?

Tags: php, yii2, fullcalendar

I am trying to change the colour of Calendar,
I have calendar like this
[calender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OSaJ.png)
what i want to do is like this [calender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCTkj.png)
i have been able to add the colour in event text but in background of that event.
here is my code.

controller:

```
 public function actionEvent(){

     $events= \app\models\Events::find()->all();   
    $tasks=[];
     foreach ($events as $eve){
    $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
    $event->id = $eve->id;
    $event->title =$eve->event_title;
    $event->start =$eve->start_date;
    $event->end =$eve->end_date;
    $event->backgroundColor = 'green';
    $event->description=$eve->event_description ." <hr><b> Location: </b>".$eve->location." " . " <br/><b> Organizer: </b>".$eve->organizer." " ;
    $tasks[] = $event;  
     }
   return $this->render('events',['events'=>$tasks,'test'=>$tasks]);
    // return $this->render('events');
}
```

View:

```
 $thame=<<<EOF
            function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
             $(this).css('background', '#DBBEBE');


            }
EOF;
    ?>
  <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(

  'events'=> $events,
  'clientOptions' => [
       // 'weekends' => true,
       // 'language' => 'fa',
        //'eventLimit' => TRUE,
       //'droppable' => true,
       // 'editable' => true,
         'theme'=>new JsExpression($thame),
       // 'fixedWeekCount' => true,
        'eventClick' => new JsExpression($ClickMe),
        'defaultDate' => date('Y-m-d'),

    ],       
));?>
```

Can anyone Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be helpful for you -

As per their documentation, you can use [eventBackgroundColor](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventBackgroundColor/).

```
{
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2011-04-04'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2011-05-05'
        }
        // etc...
    ],
    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

If you want other work around, In your custom style add the below code -

```
.fc-event{
  background-color: yellow !important; /* only use !important if calendar's default style is overwriting your style */
}
```

Comment: How exactly do that in Yii2 Widget? i am new on it

Comment: @snew are you using any `style sheet` with in your plugin.? if its there then just add the style in my answer to the style sheet.!

Comment: it only changes the background of event text. not whole day block.

Comment: oh my bad . thanks for help :)  i become able to change half of field yellow and that is enough for me.